# Spring boot kafka - how to tell JsonDeserializer to ignore type header?

Tags: json, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Spring's Kafka producer embeds type header into messages which specifies to which class the message should be deserialized by a consumer.This is a problem when the producer isn't using Spring Kafka, but the consumer is.In that case, JsonDeserializer cannot deserialize a message and will throw an exception "No type information in headers and no default type provided".
One way to get around this is to set a default deserialization type.This won't work in cases where a single topic contains multiple message schemas.
Another solution I've found is to set

> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.use.type.headers

to false (in application.properties file).This doesn't do anything as the same exception is thrown again.
How do I make sure that JsonDeserializer ignores type headers?

Answer (score 1):

See this option of that deserializer:

```
/**
 * Set to false to ignore type information in headers and use the configured
 * target type instead.
 * Only applies if the preconfigured type mapper is used.
 * Default true.
 * @param useTypeHeaders false to ignore type headers.
 * @since 2.2.8
 */
public void setUseTypeHeaders(boolean useTypeHeaders) {
```

It can be configured via property as:

```
/**
 * Kafka config property for using type headers (default true).
 * @since 2.2.3
 */
public static final String USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS = "spring.json.use.type.headers";
```

In this case the logic is going to be like this:

```
this.typeMapper.setTypePrecedence(this.useTypeHeaders ? TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID : TypePrecedence.INFERRED);
```

which means that the type for deserialization is inferred from the listener method.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#json-serde

Comment: The deserializer can't infer the type from the method signature; only the message converter can do that; with the deserializer you have to provide the default type via a property. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-json-config `JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE: Fallback type for deserialization of values if no header information is present.`

Comment: To infer the type from the listener method, use a `ByteArrayDeserializer` with a `JsonMessageConverter` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion

Comment: So where do I tell the deserializer to not use type header?Setting `spring.json.use.type.headers` to false in application.properties doesn't do anything.Is there any way to use Spring boot's auto configuration and avoid creating a new factory for every listener?It's fascinating how difficult it is to change such basic property.These type headers shouldn't even exist.

Comment: It's not "using the headers" See the error message `No type information in headers and no default type provided` - there is no type information, so you need to set `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.demo.MyDto`.

Comment: If you are using `@KafkaListener` you can override that property for each listener or, as I said, use a `ByteArrayDeserializer` and add a `JsonMessageConverter` bean which Boot will automatically wire into the container factory and the type will be inferred from the method signature.

Comment: @GaryRussell Ok, I've set `spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer` and also made a `JsonMessageConverter` bean.This only manages to convert the message to a String object., there is no type inference.Documentation says that inference can be accomplished only at the class level @KafkaListener.Since I have multiple listeners for the same topic, I have a class level @KafkaListener so this probably won't work.